# Camera control on phone not working for babylonjs vr

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, babylonjs

I can't manage to get the camera control to work on a phone using babylon `defaultVRExperience`

I can't understand what's missing. i've tried everything i can think of and i can't find any examples that work outside of the babylonjs playground.

Example of it working perfectly in babylon playground with just a few lines of code: https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#VIGXA3#38

Example of same code not working outside of babylon: http://jsfiddle.net/dr3k5oqb/

Here's an example with some stuff i found in an article about making vr stuff for phones with babylon.. not working either: https://jsfiddle.net/2cdLw0tk/2/

**Phone:** A one+ 5 with oxygenOS 9.0.9

**Browser:** Chrome Version 79.0.3945.93

Literally any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: what phone are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome v76 and forward has removed usage of `DeviceMotionEvent` for http, meaning that vr accelerometer control for chrome only works when using https

Source: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5688035094036480

This can be confirmed by just switching my example links to https and they start working on chrome on my phone.

Mudin's answer could be good to look at if you want to support safari.

Comment: perfect, you found it

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using iphone safari.

> The story is that Apple is preparing to introduce a new
>   security/privacy setting to prevent sites from being able to access a
>   device’s accelerometer and gyroscope, which means some of those VR/AR
>   items you come across online probably won’t work quite as well until
>   you give express permission to do so. [full article](https://www.applemust.com/how-and-why-to-use-motion-orientation-settings-in-ios/)

In order to use vr we should ask users to allow access to motion and orientation by using this code:

```
function onClick() 
{
    if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') 
    {
        DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
        .then(permissionState => {
            if (permissionState === 'granted') 
            {
                // DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() has been granted
            }
        })
        .catch(console.error);
       }
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mudin/ruzov0s7/2/) the babylon iphone working vr example outside the playground.

Open this [demo link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/xkod90ch/9/show/) in your phone

Comment: It seems like my issue is the fact that i'm not running on https, if i change my example links to https they start working, do you happen to know why that is?

Comment: @Bobbzorzen It could be issue with loading external libraries over http

Comment: Turns out that DeviceMotionEvent is removed for http calls in chrome 76+ https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5688035094036480 which means that the way babylon handles camera control on phones only works on https
Thanks for the help though, really appreciate it

Comment: On a side note to this - babylon already integrated requestPermission calls into the latest version (4.1) which is currently in beta